# Up-to-date South Korea level-1 administrative boundaries following land reclamation

Tags: shapefile, data, administrative-boundaries, south-korea

Because of land reclamation, South Korea's western coastline changes regularly and data is regularly outdated. For example, [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html) shapefiles describe boundaries prior to the development of [Songdo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Songdo_International_Business_District).

How can I keep up-to-date with South Korea level-1 administrative boundaries (provinces and special cities, in the form of shape files or equivalent like the "R sf" (`.rds`) format supplied by GADM)?

I've updated the reference to GADM from v2 to v3 but the v3 Korea admin 1 file has the same issues I detected in v2 so it may not have been updated.

Comment: Well, how do you do it currently?

Comment: I'm using GADM for lack of a better alternative. I can see some changes in Google's base map but they are not reflected in the admin boundaries. I've found another more up-to-date source in [Korea's NSDI](http://data.nsdi.go.kr/dataset/15144) but it has other problems (which I'm trying but not sure I can solve). So I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: It's best that you contact Songdo International Business District or the Incheon Province that if they have the latest current shapefiles you need.

Comment: This is from the University of Michigan GIS that has the Korea GiS data....not sure what you are looking for https://guides.lib.umich.edu/c.php?g=283110&p=1886160

Comment: @PROBERT The UoM links to the GADM data.

Comment: @syre - yes I know..but cannot rule out if it is the most current one... I check it out the GADM and it does not mention the latest update. So my suggest  to you to contact the University of California, Davis about that...